# How to make a background application in windows

Tags: windows, vb.net

it was really a wrong question. all u people needed to tell me was make a hidden form and write your code in onload event,still u downrated the post.

Comment: Do you want this to run as a service?  Or with a user session?

Comment: -1 this shows a complete utter lack of research effort. All you had to do was google `WebClient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be interested in creating a [windows service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service).

You should be able search for terms such as "Windows service in VB.net" to find some more in depth tutorials.

I Found an example online at [code.msdn.microsoft.com](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VBWindowsService-3fc2805b).

In case the link is broken here are a few snippets from the article:

> Step1. In Visual Studio 2010, add a new Visual Basic / Windows / Windows Service project named VBWindowsService. The project template
>   automatically adds a component class named Service1 that inherits from
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.
>
> Step2. Rename the default Service1 to the name "SampleService". Open
>   the service in designer and set the ServiceName property to be
>   VBWindowsService.
>
> Step3. To add custom event log functionality to your service, drag and
>   drop an event log component from toolbox to the design view, and set
>   its Log property to be Application, and its Source to be
>   VBWindowsService. The event log component will be used to log some
>   messages to the Application log.
>
> Step4. To define what occurs when the service starts and stops, in the
>   Code Editor, locate the OnStart and OnStop methods that were
>   automatically overridden when you created the project, and write code
>   to determine what occurs when the service starts running.
>
> NOTE: A service application is designed to be long running. Therefore,
>   it usually polls or monitors something in the system. The monitoring
>   is set up in the OnStart method. However, OnStart does not actually do
>   the monitoring. The OnStart method must return to the operating system
>   after the service's operation has begun. It must not loop forever or
>   block. To set up a simple monitoring mechanism, one general solution
>   is to create a timer in OnStart. The timer would then raise events in
>   your code periodically, at which time your service could do its
>   monitoring. The other solution is to spawn a new thread to perform the main service functions.

I removed references to some of the specifics of the example and omitted the source code.

Comment: Hi Matthew Sanders, it's customary in StackOverflow (and Superuser) answers to include a summary of the contents of a link or the highlights that specifically answer the question. The goal of SE sites is to become a resource of knowledge, of answers, for years to come. With a link-only answer, the op must dig through another resource to locate an answer he/she might not be sure about. Most importantly, if your link were to ever break, your answer is useless for anyone who visits this page in the future. Consider making an edit to your answer to add more details. Good luck!

Comment: I agree and apologize for my first answer @Jeremy Thompson.  I was assuming that the post would likely not remain open for long as it is pretty vague.  The main point was to alert the author to the possibility of employing a windows service.  Once you know the terminology it is fairly simple to find more information.

Comment: dont worry guys, i hav got what i needed, i was planning a remote controlling software , n i have made that now, thanx for your answers!!